# My app 'Qt' runs in my computer but does not run on my friend's

Tags: c++, windows, qt, deployment

I have a problem as I mentioned in the title, when I run it in my computer it's totally fine even if I moved the .exe file to another folder, but it cannot be run in my friend's, I tried to build it using 64bit and 86bit but still the same problem.

This is the error:

`the application was unable to start correctly 0xc00007b`

I've searched and found that it's because of the .dlls but how can I know which dll?

Edit: answering the question:

I'm using Qt 5.1.1 I built it statically , and my compiler is msvc11 86x.

problem:: Edit:

after assuming that my friend's windows has some problems since he really does have some problems , I installed a virtual one using virtualbox " windows 7 32bit " when I moved my app it really asked for `msvcp110.dll` and `msvcr110.dll` , but after downloading them from a website now it says:

> the procedure entry point _crt create symbolic link w could not be
>   located in the dynamic link library msvcr110.dll

not sure should the files be from my windows or it's ok to download it from websites like dlls-files ?

Edit 3:

I solved it after deleting all the msvc dlls that I've downloaded manually when it asked , and I updated the windows and installed every version of the things that you guys listed and it works , but you need to delete the files that you've downloaded first otherwise it won't work.

thanks for all your help.

Comment: What is your compiler and which version of Qt are you using?

Comment: Have you tried [Googling the error message?](https://www.google.com/search?q=the+application+was+unable+to+start+correctly+0xc00007b)  Several posts seems to suggest that there is a problem with your friend's windows installation, either disk corruption or some missing or broken DLL's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are dynamically linking to Qt, you should place Qt DLLs along the release version of your executable. These are `Qt5Core.dll`, `Qt5Gui.dll` and possibly the ones for other modules that you have used. These dll files are in your installed Qt Directory in bin folder.

You should also place `msvcr110.dll` and `msvcp110.dll` in case you are using MSVS2011. If you are using plugins you should place their dll in a folder named `plugins` beside your exe. In case of using icons and images you should ship their dlls like `qico.dll` and `qsvg.dll` in a folder named `imageformats`.

Comment: Thanks ,I'm statically linking Qt , you helped a lot, I gave him msvcp110 but not msvcr110 , I'll give him that file and hopefully it'll work.

Comment: Use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to figure out exactly which DLLs you need to ship.

Comment: You may need to install the MSVC C++ redistributables package for the year of VS tools you are using from microsoft, so that they get the right ones.